# Is there a conditional in Wordpress for a specific tag page?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, tags, conditional-statements

I want to change the meta description on my Wordpress website for a certain page that queries all the posts containing a certain tag.

The page I am talking about looks like this:

mainwebsite.com/tag/tag-name

So I want to add in the header.php file a conditional where I can change the meta description only on that page. I tried the following:

```
<?php if(has_tag('this-is-the-tag-name')){
echo 'test';
}
?>
```

And this puts "test" on every single tag page. I want the change to apply only on the tag page "this-is-the-tag-name."

Comment: Have you tried with `is_tag( 'this-is-the-tag-name' )` ? Also try with specifying tag_id in the `has_tag` function ?

Answer (score 0):

Say your tag name is "slug". Look at the template hierarchy for tags. Wordpress will start from the top, and work its way down until it finds an available template to display the tag

> tag-slug.php >  tag-id.php >  tag.php >  archive.php >  index.php

With that said, if you create a template called `tag-slug.php`, you can simply add a `if( is_page_template( 'tag-slug.php' ))` statement to your header or functions.php, and your conditions will only display on that specific page.